# Windows Form->DataGridView->DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Uncheck All Leaves One Item Checked

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

We have a very strange problem in a Windows Form that we cannot seem to figure out.

Our Windows Form has a DataGridView with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in the first column.

[image]

We've added a the following functionality that allows a user to shift->click to select multiple rows in this grid:

```
int colHit = gvLibrary.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
        int lastRowHit;
        //mouse left click
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (colHit == 0)
            {
                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                {
                    lastRowHit = gvLibrary.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
                    ShiftClickCheckBoxSetter(this.gvLibrary, int.Parse(txtFirstClickRow.Text), lastRowHit);

                }
                else
                {
                    int firstRowHit = gvLibrary.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
                    txtFirstClickRow.Text = firstRowHit.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the CheckBoxSetter Code:

```
  private void ShiftClickCheckBoxSetter(DataGridView dataGridView, int p, int lastRowHit)
    {
        if (p < lastRowHit)
        {
            for (int i = p; i < lastRowHit; i++)
            {
                dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;
            }
        }
        else//
        {
            for (int i = p; i >= lastRowHit; i--)
            {
                dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is working as expected.

[image]

We've also added a ContextMenuStrip to the control for a right-click event.

```
 else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (colHit != 0)
            {
                ContextMenuStrip m = new ContextMenuStrip();
                m.Items.Add("Select All", null, m_LibraryItemClicked);
                m.Items.Add("Select None", null, m_LibraryItemClickedNone);
                m.Show(gvLibrary, e.Location);
            }
        }
```

Delegate Event One:

```
     void m_LibraryItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in gvLibrary.Rows)
        {
            if (dgvr.Selected) {
                dgvr.Selected = false;
            }

            dgvr.Cells["LSelect"].Value = true;
        }
    }
```

Delegate Event Two:

```
 private void m_LibraryItemClickedNone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in gvLibrary.Rows)
        {
            if (dgvr.Selected)
               dgvr.Selected = false;

            dgvr.Cells["LSelect"].Value = false;
        }
    }
```

This allows to the user to select all or select none for the checkboxes.

[image: Select All/Select None]

When the Select All selection is chosen, all check boxes are checked:

[image: All Selected]

However when the Select None option is selected:

[image: Select None]

All check boxes are de-selected, except for the last one checked in the Shift-Click event:

[image: All But One]

I would think that iterating through all of the Grid Rows and setting the checkbox to not selected would suffice, IE:

```
 private void m_LibraryItemClickedNone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in gvLibrary.Rows)
        {
            if (dgvr.Selected)
               dgvr.Selected = false;

            dgvr.Cells["LSelect"].Value = false;
        }
    }
```

However there seems to be some kind of state property that is disallowing this checkbox in that row to be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to debug whole scenario using break points?

Comment: Yes, we have done that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and could reproduce this behaviour. The problem seem to be with the current cell (not the cell selected). When you try to change this particular cell, the action doesn't get executed immediately.

To change this behaviour add a `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;` before changing the value of the "LSelect" cell. This should fix your issue.

```
private void m_LibraryItemClickedNone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;    
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in gvLibrary.Rows)
    {
        if (dgvr.Selected)
           dgvr.Selected = false;

        dgvr.Cells["LSelect"].Value = false;
    }
}
```